# Problem with cds.RecordCount

Tags: database, performance, delphi, record-count

Is there a problem with cds.RecordCount ?

I usually use it to determine if I have any records in a query.

But talking with a college he told that there is a performance penalty to that!

I have made some test and nothing major came up.

So is there a performance penalty or any other problem with RecordCount?!

If so, what is the best way to check if there are some records in a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using TClientDataSet (as your 'cds' seems to imply) with `PacketRecords` set to `-1` (default) or `FetchOnDemand` set to `False` there is no difference since the client dataset receives and loads all data into memory at once.
The difference would be noticable with other datasets which fetch data on demand as you advance the cursor, using `RecordCount` would fetch all data first. In such cases it's better to use the dataset's `EOF` property after opening - if all you want to know is whether the result set was empty or not.

Comment: `TClientDataSet` also supports local caching and fetch on demand.

Comment: @Jørn Thanks, I added note about PacketRecords = -1 when fetching on demand is disabled. Not sure what you mean by local caching or how it's relevant to the question.

Comment: The RecordCount method will show the numer of locally cached records IIRC.  It will not fetch all records first.  Although this might be implementet differently in different TDataSet descendants.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.

If you need all records locally, you should set the `FetchOnDemand` property to `False` or you can call `cds.Last` right before `cds.RecordCount`.

There is also a `cds.IsEmpty` method if the purpose is to check whether the dataset contains records...